# How can I automate WiX packaging

Tags: xml, build, wix, build-automation, packaging

I want to try create a set of WiX projects for each application we have. The idea is that once a developer is ready to release an updated version of an app, he/she would copy the Source files to a SourceDir, and then execute a .bat file which will execute heat.exe to get a list of files that need to be packaged, and thereafter Candle and Ligth will compile the Source into an msi.

I also want to modify the App.config file when building the package with values public properties. Through my investigation I have figured out that I can do this using . The problem is though I need to do this by adding util:XmlFile Id="SetKey1" ... under the configuration file Componenet element.

```
      <Component Id="App.config" Guid="{B62F28B1-FFB3-4E93-B651-FFC7AAD4730D}">
        <File Id="App.config" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\New Folder\New Folder2\App.config" />
        <util:XmlFile Id="SetKey1"
            Action="setValue"
            ElementPath="//appSettings/add[\[]@key='Key1'[\]]/@value"
            Value="[NEWVALUE]"
            File="[#App.config]"
            SelectionLanguage="XPath"
            Sequence="1" />
      </Component>
```

This is no good as that bit dissapears when you run heat next time around. Is there a way to segregate the bit where the config file is modified

Answer (score 0):

You should have at least 2 wxis. 1 would be for the main Product and contain the components and the other would be the HEATed files.

In the main Product.wxs (or whatever you call it) can specify Directories and when you run heat you can specify a directory ref.

ie.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="MyApp">
        <Directory Id="WEBROOT" Name="wwwroot" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
```

When you run heat you would specify the directoryref as WEBROOT, then as long as you compile the WXS both together the files will be included.

eg. Heat [other params] -dr WEBROOT

Comment: Thanks daniel, thanks for that, can you help me with this as well. say one of the components was an app.config file which I want to overwrite with a public property value how can I reference that component from outside the heated wxis file to modify it using util:XmlFile